# How to join table columns in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I create a column as a combination of two (or more) columns? I have to select the desired columns by name:

Table:

```
A   B   C   D
1   5   7   4
2   8   4   9
8   5   7   4
```

It should become:

```
AC  BD
1   5
2   8
8   5
7   4
4   9
7   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way with gnuplot to add columns (or concatenate or join) with writing also a header. Use the potting style `with table` and write the new data into a datablock. Default column separator is whitespace (if you write it to a file you will see that it will be TAB with an additional space). But you can set any other character, check `help table`.

**Script:**

```
### join columns
reset session

$Data  <<EOD
A   B   C   D
1   5   7   4
2   8   4   9
8   5   7   4
EOD

set table $Joined
    plot '+' u ("AC    BD") every ::::0 w table, \
       $Data u "A":"B" w table, \
       $Data u "C":"D" w table
unset table

print $Joined
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
AC    BD
 1       5
 2       8
 8       5
 7       4
 4       9
 7       4
```

Comment: I just realized that I should better keep the first column. So the final table should look like this: first AC BD. I know that the entries in the first column are simply repeated. But I can't customize the plot command.

Comment: Clever one, this. Never occurred to me to use several "w table" in one plot. ;) +1

Comment: @Karl what's the problem with using `''` the second time? Will it not work anymore in newer versions?

Comment: @theozh It's not documented actually, and not guaranteed to keep working. It's super handy, undoubtedly. ;)

Comment: @Karl actually, it's *well* documented and available at least since gnuplot 4.6.0 (March 2012). Check `help special-filenames`: "The empty filename `''` tells gnuplot to re-use the previous input file in the same plot command".

Comment: it's far older, I use gnuplot since 3.7, and it was there already. I vaguely remember some old newsgroup discussion about it, but maybe the status has changed since then, or my memory fails me. ;)

Comment: @Karl ok, this was before my gnuplot time ;-). Yes, I found it also in 4.0 (2004) documentation. Older versions I don' have. But why do you think it might be depreciated?

Comment: I'd have to do some serious spelunking in the archives to find that post, frankly I don't remember exactly. It works across (re)plots, maybe that was the issue. Anyway it's clearly meant to save you some typing on the command line, in a script I would always use a variable for the file name. And neither that variable nor a $datablock are actual file names, so your use was arguably somewhat outside of the documented usage, too.